# Can Control Variables also be included as Dependent Variables?

Tags: regression, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm currently reading an academic journal (http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2488863) which, in Table 11 of the paper, lists several control variables including:

- Returns
- Size
- Leverage
- Growth

And it runs regressions of say:

- Overinvestment = bo + b1returns + b2Size + b3Leverage...

However, it also considers leverage as an dependent variable for one of these regressions:

- Leverage = b0 + b1returns + b2Size + ...

Is this logical? I'm a student of econometrics and haven't seen this done before, but was wondering if this was a badly thought through approach, or (more likely) that i'm missing something.

Comment: No it is not typically common, in fact it is the definition of a bad control